# Solr search facets name with regular expression

Tags: regex, solr

I wanted to filter facets name based on regular expression. 
I have an idea of facet.prefix element and im expecting an similar feature to find facets by providing keywords that can be somewhere in between the whole work.

example :- facets country["united states","west indies","india"].
required feature: search all facets name containing "ind" keyword. resulting "west indies" and "india".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<=")[a-zA-z -]*ind[a-zA-z -]*(?=")` will do it for you, dont know what sort of exceptions will you have in your data

Comment: @kumar-kailash: if this was the answer you were looking for, how about an upvote for @joao-raposo?

Answer (score 0):

Solr has a facet.contains parameter, that allows to filter by sub-string containing in the middle of facet

For more details please see:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.contains.ignoreCaseParameter